# Fibonacci in leetcode

Tags: python, indexing, fibonacci

Given a value `n` I want to calculate the `nth` Fibonacci Number.

I ran my code in VScode and got correct results but when I submit my code  in leetcode I am getting an Error.

Do you know what's wrong?

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self, n: int) -> int:
        m = n+1
        f = ['']*m
        f[0] = 0
        f[1] = 1
        for i in range(2, m):
            f[i] = f[i-1]+f[i-2]
        return(f[-1])
```

Comment: The error in leetcode is "List assignment is out of index" for f[1]=1

Comment: Your code doesn't print correct Fibonacci numbers

Answer (score 0):

What if **n == 0?** Your code will fail when assigning f[1] = 1. Size of f is 1 and you are trying to update 2nd index of it.

Comment: Thank you! I got it.

Comment: If you find this useful, you may consider to upvote and accept as solution. That will be helpful for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a logical answer. As @ankush_ stated, if `n=0`, then there is only one element. And, your code will raise an error.

```
class Solution:
    def fib(self,n):
        a, b = 0, 1
        c=a
        while a < n:
            c=a
            a, b = b, a+b
        return c
x=Solution()
print("Last Fibonacci Number:",x.fib(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if n==0:
        return 0
    m = n+1
    f = ['']*m
    f[0] = 0
    f[1] = 1
    for i in range(2, m):
        f[i] = f[i-1]+f[i-2]
    return(f[-1])
```

so this is the answer